# Makefile execute phonytargets of a file only if file does not exists

Tags: makefile, dependencies

Is there any way I can only execute the phony dependency of a file
if this file does not exist?

If the file has no phony dependency it works and only executes the content
of this rule. But if I add a phony target as dependency it keeps executing the dependency rule and the rule of generating the existing file.

I simplified my Makefile so you can see my problem:

```
 
.PHONY: phonytarget all clean

all: $(CURDIR)/a.a
    @echo done

$(CURDIR)/a.a: phonytarget
    @touch $@

phonytarget:
    @echo what the heck is wrong with you
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case, you want to define order-only prerequisites. Order-only prerequisites can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (`|`) in the prerequisites list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any prerequisites to the right are order-only:
>
> ```
> targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites
> ```
>
> The normal prerequisites section may of course be empty. Also, you may still declare multiple lines of prerequisites for the same target: they are appended appropriately (normal prerequisites are appended to the list of normal prerequisites; order-only prerequisites are appended to the list of order-only prerequisites).

```
.PHONY: phonytarget all clean

all: $(CURDIR)/a.a
    @echo done

$(CURDIR)/a.a: | phonytarget
    @touch $@

phonytarget:
    @echo what the hack is wrong with you
```

Comment: 'what the hack is wrong with you' is still shown everytime running the code, make 4.2.1

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me either, I'm using GNU Make 4.3 and see both messages printed every time.

Comment: order-only-prerequisites still adds the dependency target to execution, it just skips `$(CURDIR)/a.a` if the file already exists

Answer (score 2):

Recursive make call works for me:

```
.PHONY: phonytarget all clean

all: $(CURDIR)/a.a
    @echo done

$(CURDIR)/a.a:
    @$(MAKE) phonytarget
    @touch $@

phonytarget:
    @echo what the heck is wrong with you
```

It is ugly, I know. Hope someone will suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can define targets that should be considered soft dependencies with [`INTERMEDIATE:`](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_node/make_98.html#SEC97)

```
.INTERMEDIATE: foo

a: foo
    @echo running a
    @touch a

foo:
    @echo running foo
```

Note that if you have your soft target marked as `.PHONY`, this wouldn't work.

If your soft target is an actual file, you can also use `.SECONDARY` instead to mark the file as intermediate and prevent automatic deletion.